# Getting Total Cost in xquery (multiplication and addition)

Tags: xml, xquery

Trying to get the total amount ordered in XQuery but running into some issues.

This is the OrderLine.xml

```
<OrderLine>
  <OrderNum>21610</OrderNum>
  <PartNum>DR93</PartNum>
  <NumOrdered>1</NumOrdered>
  <QuotedPrice>495.00</QuotedPrice>
</OrderLine>
<OrderLine>
  <OrderNum>21610</OrderNum>
  <PartNum>DW11</PartNum>
  <NumOrdered>1</NumOrdered>
  <QuotedPrice>399.99</QuotedPrice>
</OrderLine>
```

I need to get the total amount per order. This is my xquery:

```
for $ln1 in doc("../premiere/OrderLine.xml")//OrderLine[OrderNum = $ord/OrderNum]
let $total := ($ln1/NumOrdered * $ln1/QuotedPrice)
where $ord/CustomerNum = $cus/CustomerNum

return
<orderRevenue TotalAmount= "{$total}" />
```

which runs fine when there's only one order in the system, but when there are multiple orders, then I get two total amounts.

I get this:

```
<orderRevenue TotalAmount="495"/>
<orderRevenue TotalAmount="399.99"/>
```

when I should be getting this:

```
<orderRevenue TotalAmount="$894.99"/>
```

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I would simply use a step with `/(NumOrdered * QuotedPrice)` or the map operator `!` with e.g. `!(NumOrdered * QuotedPrice)` and then call the `sum` function on the result:

```xquery
declare variable $order-num as xs:integer external := 21610;

<orderRevenue TotalAmount="${sum(//OrderLine[OrderNum = $order-num]!(NumOrdered * QuotedPrice))}"/>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWV9 for the `!` example and https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWV9/1 for the step example.

Or use `sum` on the result of a `for` expression:

```xquery
let $total := 
  sum(
    for $ol in //OrderLine[OrderNum = $order-num]
    return $ol/NumOrdered * $ol/QuotedPrice
  )
return
  <orderRevenue TotalAmount="${$total}"/>
```

https://xqueryfiddle.liberty-development.net/b4GWV9/2